# Compiled C programme for storing confidential information

Tags: c, security

I always thought that once compiled the source file could not be extracted from a C programme. I have since read the sometimes it can be. Is storing passwords this way secure?

```
int main() {

printf("\nemail@example.com password: 123123\n\n");

return 0;

}
```

Comment: It is not in the least bit secure.

Comment: No, as this can be easily [Reverse engineered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_engineering#Software).

Comment: Also, are you going to delete the source code file after compilation?

Comment: Also see [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/150599/is-it-safe-to-store-a-password-in-compiled-code)

Comment: Weather Vane - I would store the original file in an encrypted disk image with a long random password.

Comment: Compiling a C source makes the program logic harder to read. But if the program needs to deal with strings like names, email addresses etc. they are stored as plain text. Compiling is not encryption. Just by looking at the executable in a hex editor (or sometimes even text editor) will reveal the strings. Then it is only a small step to guess what a string might mean.

Comment: In this case you've put the password in the *same string* as the information telling you what it is.

Comment: To read data you don't even need to disassemble or reverse-engineer the executable, just open it with an hex editor (or even notepad ;-) ).

Answer (score 2):

You can easily see for yourself. After adding `#include <stdio.h>`, try these commands (assuming you have *gcc* and standard unix tools like *strings*):

```
$ gcc -O3 yourcode.c -o yourcode
$ strings yourcode
email@example.com password: 123123
```

As you can see, the string literals are not encoded in any way, they are in the application binary as is.

---

More generally, even if you try to encrypt the password in the binary, if the application itself can decode it, then so can anybody who can run the application. If the "secret" data is encrypted, but encryption key is with the application, then the encryption is just obfuscation, not real security.

Even if you make it impossible to see the "secret" data by examining the binary directly, the snooper can always run the application under debugger, possibly under a virtual machine, and wait for the application to decode the secret information, as it must do to use it.

[*Security through obscurity is no security*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) has been said by several people in different forms, predating computers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your replies. I could not open the compiled programme in BBEdit which made me think it maybe couldn't be opened. However it opened easily in Smultron and Text Exit. Not a problem of course as I use encrypted disk images and an encrypted USB drive.
"Security through obscurity is no security" - a good quote, which is why I never use hidden folders.